# Editing iTunes Metadata

Tags: cocoa, metadata, avfoundation, itunes, editing

I'm trying to move from atomicparsley to AVFoundtation for editing a movie's iTunes metadata.  The problem is that I can't seem to find a way of editing "inline".  Unless I missed something obvious, it seems that both AVAssetExportSession and AVAssetWriter will only write to a new file.  So every time something like the movie title, or the audio gain is changed, the whole file is written to disk.  This is not what happens in iTunes, so there seems to be some way of doing this.  Or is this data that iTunes keeps separately in some sort of library file?  But then what happens when a video is exported to an iPhone say?  Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.